# group records which contain string

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've a table with following data:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | country         |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | i'm from usa    |
|  2 | i'm from italy  |
|  3 | i'm from china  |
|  4 | i'm from india  |
|  5 | she's from usa  |
|  6 | he's from china |
+----+-----------------+
```

I want to know the population of each country, by checking country name in the `country` column.
I want something like this:

```
+---------+------------+
| country | population |
+---------+------------+
| usa     | 2          |
| italy   | 1          |
| china   | 2          |
| india   | 1          |
+---------+------------+
```

I think I should use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` function. But How?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If the country is always at the end you can use this.

```
select
  case 
    when country like '%usa' then 'usa'
    when country like '%italy' then 'italy'
    when country like '%china' then 'china'
    when country like '%india' then 'india'
  end as ccountry,
  count(*) as population
from Table1
group by ccountry;
```

If country can be anywhere in the string you can find it like this assuming it is at the beginning, at the end or in the middle surrounded by `space`.

```
select
  case 
    when country like '% usa %' then 'usa'
    when country like '% italy %' then 'italy'
    when country like '% china %' then 'china'
    when country like '% india %' then 'india'
  end as ccountry,
  count(*) as population
from 
    (
      select concat(' ', country, ' ') as country
      from Table1
    ) T
group by ccountry
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the country name is always the last component of `country` (where components are delimited by spaces), then you could do this:

```
select substring_index(country, ' ', -1) as real_country, count(*)
from your_table
group by real_country
```

The [`substring_index(country, ' ', -1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) gives you the last "word" of country.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but may be the solution

```
select SUBSTRING(country,(INSTR(country,'from') +5)), count(1) 
from table group by SUBSTRING(country,(INSTR(country,'from') +5))
```

Comment: thanks, but can you explain it? what does '+5' mean here? and if the country name wasn't at this position (in the string), for example it was at the start or position 50 (in a long text), can it finds it?

Comment: instr function finds the text position. in this post, it looks for 'from' text, and returns first occurrence. i'm from america example, it returns 5. for accessing index of america, we have to add 5 for 'from ' text char.

Comment: i assume that country names comes always after 'from ' text

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(country, ' ', '.'), 1) as parsedCountry, count(*) AS population
FROM table
GROUP BY parsedCountry
```

Explanation:
1.
    REPLACE(country, ' ', '.')
Just replaces all space ocurrences with a dot. So "she's from usa" will be "she's.from.usa"

2.
    PARSENAME("she's.from.usa", 1)
Will split the string on the dots. And then count 1 from back to front and get that part of the string. Will return "usa"

3.
    FROM table
I dont know what's the name of your table...So I put table.

4.
    GROUP BY parsedCountry
its gonna group the after-parsename-replace-country ocurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option if your 'country' name can come from another table. This has the flexibility to grow as your 'country' names list grows, without having to get in and edit the SQL statements.

I created a temporary table #citizens to match your example input:

```
create table #citizens (id int, country varchar(30) )

insert into #citizens (id, country) values (1, 'i''m from usa')
insert into #citizens (id, country) values (2, 'i''m from italy')
insert into #citizens (id, country) values (3, 'i''m from china')
insert into #citizens (id, country) values (4, 'i''m from india')
insert into #citizens (id, country) values (5, 'she''s from usa')
insert into #citizens (id, country) values (6, 'he''s from china')
```

Then I created a temporary table #countries to hold the country names for the select

```
create table #countries (country varchar(30) )

insert into #countries values('usa')
insert into #countries values('china')
insert into #countries values('india')
insert into #countries values('italy')
```

The required select would look like this.  Notice the **like '%'**...

```
select co.country, COUNT(*) 
from #countries co
left outer join #citizens ci on ci.country like '%'+co.country+'%'
group by co.country
```

Since I was just playing around, I dropped the temporary tables afterwards.

```
drop table #countries
drop table #citizens
```